# Pandas read_sql very slow in Docker container on WSL2

Tags: python, pandas, docker, sqlalchemy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a Docker application on WSL2 on Windows 10. I'm have containers for a Flask app, Celery worker (haven't gotten to getting it to work yet), Redis, and a Traefik reverse proxy.

My Flask app is served using Waitress. Outside of the Docker container, the application loads perfectly. It takes about 3 seconds to load the page. In the Docker container, it takes over 5 minutes.

I use pandas.read_sql to pull data from a MSSQL database. My query pulls outside of docker averaged .02 seconds. Inside docker they average 2.7 seconds.

I don't think its a memory or CPU problem, because I docker stats shows that the memory and CPU don't spike over 8% and 4% respectively unless that doesn't show the full story.

Below are what some of my files look like. Please let me know if you want to see anything else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: I've used Docker before, but it was straight on Windows. Basically everything is the same except I added Celery/Redis and I'm on WSL2 now. And I didn't have this issue before.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  home:
    restart: always
    image: home_dev
    networks:
      - traefik
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./home/Dockerfile.flask
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - home_worker
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.home_http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.home_http.rule=Host(`localhost`)
      - traefik.enable=true

  home_worker:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./home/Dockerfile.celery
    networks:
      - traefik
    command: poetry run celery -A tasks worker -l info -E
    environment:
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.10.3
    networks:
      - traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik=true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      #- 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    
  redis:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik
    image: redis:7
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
```

Dockerfile.flask:

```
FROM python:3.11

# redis config
ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

EXPOSE 5000

# instal odbc drivers
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

COPY /home/home ./app/home
COPY /home/static ./app/static
COPY /home/templates ./app/templates
COPY /home/app.py ./app/app.py
COPY /home/poetry.lock ./app/poetry.lock
COPY /home/pyproject.toml ./app/pyproject.toml
COPY /home/waitress_server.py ./app/waitress_server.py
COPY /home/README.md ./app/README.md
COPY /toolbox ./toolbox

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install poetry==1.3.2
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
RUN poetry install

# Run app
CMD poetry run python -u waitress_server.py
#CMD poetry run python app.py
```

SQL Pull Function:

```
def pull_query(query, database=None):
    if database:
        engine = connection(database)
    else:
        engine = connection()
    if engine:
        df = read_sql(query, engine)
        return df
    else: 
        return None

def connection(database='master', username=None, password=None):
    username = getenv('SQL_USER')
    password = getenv('SQL_PASSWORD')
    server = getenv('SQL_SERVER')
    connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password + ';Encrypt=no'
    connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    try:
        engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    except:
        engine = None
    return engine
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but I had issues with ipv6 vs ipv4 and also DNS resolution.  Maybe open shell on running instance and check DNS resolution, then trying ipv4 addresses and ipv6 addresses.  I think I used ping and you can force it to ping ipv4 or ipv6 explicitly with command line arguments when targeting a domain (`-4` or `-6`).   I got lost in the weeds a long time before I realized it was completely unrelated to my actual app.  This was regular linux though so might be completely unrelated to your problem but it is an easy check.

Comment: @IanWilson Thanks for the comment. Doesn't seem like that's the issue. The site connects fine and I can see it running through my python code. It is just the sql database pulls that take significantly longer. I'm thinking it has something to do with essentially running a vm within a vm since I'm using WSL2.